# In Angular, how can I add a class sequentially to a group of items

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a simple swipeRight function. I have 4 circles that I want to add a class to every time the user swipes right. So on the first swipe right, the first circle should have a class added. 2nd swipe, 2nd circle has a class added. Etc.

Not sure how to go about this in Angular.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you share the code you're currently working with? Once we have this we will be able to try and pinpoint where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this isn't using Angular this should help point you in the right direction.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WoJjON

```
$('#circles').mouseenter(function(){ // Update the event handler to your 'swipeRight' event
  $ ('.circle').each(function(){
    if (!$(this).hasClass('newClass')){
      $(this).addClass('newClass');
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't even thinking to use just standard jQuery. Thought I could have done something cool w/Angular. Perfect!